# How to remove attribute from xml using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove unnessary attribute from my xml file. I know we can remove by xsl. But i don't know how to do it. I search on internet i can't get expect result.

Here is current my xml output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rsm:Invoice xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:rsm="http://www.ita.org/" 
xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:standard:CoreComponentsTechnicalSpecification:2" 
xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:2" 
xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:2" 
xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:2" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ita.org/ Invoice_20.xsd">
  <rsm:HeaderExchangedDocument>
    <ram:ID xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/">103004</ram:ID>
    <ram:TypeCode xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/">Invoice</ram:TypeCode>
    <ram:IssueDateTime xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/">2014-01-01</ram:IssueDateTime>
    <ram:CopyIndicator xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/">Original</ram:CopyIndicator>
    <ram:CustomsID xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/" />
    <ram:HeaderInformation xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/" />
    <ram:SummaryInformation xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/" />
  </rsm:HeaderExchangedDocument>
  <rsm:SpecifiedLogisticsConsignment>
    <ram:IncludedSupplyChainConsignment xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/">
      <ram:BorderCrossingLogisticsTransportMovement>
        <ram:ModeCode>1</ram:ModeCode>
        <ram:Mode>Sea</ram:Mode>
        <ram:ID />
      </ram:BorderCrossingLogisticsTransportMovement>
    </ram:IncludedSupplyChainConsignment>
  </rsm:SpecifiedLogisticsConsignment>
</rsm:Invoice>
```

I want to get below format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsm:Invoice xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:rsm="http://www.ita.org/" 
xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:standard:TechnicalSpecification:2" 
xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:2" 
xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:2" 
xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:2" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ita.org/ Invoice_20.xsd">
  <rsm:HeaderExchangedDocument>
    <ram:ID>103004</ram:ID>
    <ram:TypeCode>Invoice</ram:TypeCode>
    <ram:IssueDateTime>2014-01-01</ram:IssueDateTime>
    <ram:CopyIndicator>Original</ram:CopyIndicator>
    <ram:CustomsID/>
    <ram:HeaderInformation/>
    <ram:SummaryInformation/>
  </rsm:HeaderExchangedDocument>
  <rsm:SpecifiedLogisticsConsignment>
    <ram:IncludedSupplyChainConsignment>
      <ram:BorderCrossingLogisticsTransportMovement>
        <ram:ModeCode>1</ram:ModeCode>
        <ram:Mode>Sea</ram:Mode>
        <ram:ID />
      </ram:BorderCrossingLogisticsTransportMovement>
    </ram:IncludedSupplyChainConsignment>
  </rsm:SpecifiedLogisticsConsignment>
</rsm:Invoice>
```

How may i do in xslt?

Comment: They are not unnecessary attributes, but namespace declarations. You appear to have 2 different namespace declarations for the ram prefix. Should ram:ID and the others be rsm:ID?

Comment: You're right. But my software cannot create two namespace. And I just follow the user requirement. So i want to remove unnecessay "attribute" from "ram:ID".

Comment: assigning one prefix to multiple namespaces is possible, but hardly a good idea - it's really confusing. Your soft already generates 2 namespaces; but it seems that you forced it somehow to override "ram" prefix to a different value, which it (correctly) resolves by specifying the desired namespace declaration on elements. Just generating the first part with "rsm" prefix will probably make what your elements attributeless; but it's not clear from your question if it breaks the user requirements.

Comment: Please, edit the question and specify exactly which attributes must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ram:ID is being output as an element in the namespace "http://www.ita.org/", and you want it as an element in the namespace "urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:2"

So whatever code is generating it is putting it in the wrong namespace and needs to be fixed; you haven't shown your code so we can't tell you where it's wrong.

The trouble about googling for answers is that if you don't understand the concepts of the language you are using, you will google for the wrong thing. Your problem is not removing an attribute, but correcting an element name. Forget google for a while, and forget coding as well, and instead read a good book on XSLT.

Comment: Hi Michael and all,

    Thanks for your answer. That xml is i generated from MS Navision. Specially i can't declared namespace by run-time. So i set namespace in property. 

    <ram:ID xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/">103004</ram:ID>

I'm not declare namespace for above line. System is generated. So that i want to remove "xmlns:ram="http://www.ita.org/" in <ram:ID> element.

If you wish i can be upload image

Comment: No I don't wish you to upload an image. I wish you to follow my advice: read a book and learn the concepts.